# Extracting Json Data from List using python

Tags: python, json

I have this sample json data in a list:

```
data = [ 
  { "Name": "John_Doe", "Age" : 25 } 
  { "Name": "Jane_Roe", "Age" : 26 }
]
```

I need a way to extract the all the key value pairs from an element in the list based on the 'Name' Key. If my variable = 'John_Doe', then the script should only return the values related to John_Doe, i, e only the following values :

```
{ "Name": "John_Doe", "Age" : 25 }
```

Comment: `[x for x in data if x["Name"]=="John_Doe"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extract all the dictionaries with the value `"John_Doe"` associated with the key `"Name"`:

```
print([d for d in data if d['Name'] == "John_Doe"])
# [{ "Name": "John_Doe", "Age" : 25 }]
```

Or with [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
print(list(filter(lambda x : x['Name'] == "John_Doe", data)))
# [{ "Name": "John_Doe", "Age" : 25 }]
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is the dict with a `Name` element matching `John_Doe`, then:

```
matches = [m for m in data if "Name" in m and m["Name"] == "John_Doe"]
```

You can unroll this list comprehension to see what it does:

```
matches = []
for m in data:
    if "Name" in m and m["Name"] == "John_Doe":
        matches.append[m]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_details(data, name):
    for i in data:
        if i['Name'] == name:
            return i
    return {}

data = [{"Name": "John_Doe", "Age" : 25 },{"Name": "Jane_Roe", "Age" : 26 }]
name = "John_Doe"
get_details(data, name)
```

output:

```
{'Age': 25, 'Name': 'John_Doe'}
```